# criterion of positive definite matrix

Tags: inverse, positive-definite

I have a trouble to prove the following

let $I_n$ be the  $n\times n$ identity matrix and $A$ is $n\times n$  positive semi-definite matrix
and $b$ is a positive scalar.

Now, can we say $I_n-(I_n+bA)^{-1}$ is also positive definite?

We may assume A is non singular.
then how can I prove this?

Comment: This seems false. Suppose $A \equiv 0$.

Comment: We assume A is non singular so A is not 0 matrices

Comment: Then you should just assume $A$ is positive definite, and not positive semi-definite.

Comment: thank you and what happen if A is positive definite? it it true?

Comment: It doesn't look like it should be true, but I'm looking at it now.

Comment: Eigenvalue decomposition? Hint: $1 - \frac1{1+a} = \frac{a}{1+a} > 0$ for $a>0$.

Comment: thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, This seems to mean it is true. Let $(\lambda, x)$ be an eigenpair of the matrix $A$, with $\lambda > 0$. Then we know that
$$ (I_n + b A)^{-1}x = \frac{1}{1 + b \lambda} x. $$
Also, we then see
$$ [I_n -  (I_n + b A)^{-1}]x = \left(1 -  \frac{1}{1 + b \lambda} \right) x. $$
Since $b, \lambda > 0$ we see that the eigenvalue is also positive. Since eigenpair was arbitrary, this proves the claim.

Comment: thank you so much!! I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of setting too much abstraction against the OP: The answer remains **Yes** in the infinite-dimensional situation, i.e., $\,A\,$ is a bounded linear operator acting on a Hilbert space, and moreover if no eigenvectors at all exist.

$C=bA\,$ is then a positive definite operator, and the further proof reads as if we were dealing with positive reals:
$$
0<C\;\implies\; I<I+C\;\implies\; (I+C)^{-1}<I\;\implies\; -I<-(I+C)^{-1} \\[1.5ex]
\implies\;0<I-(I+C)^{-1}
$$